# Any oracle aggregate function that I can use in place of this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

two tables x and y.

```
table x (id, a, b, c)
1, aval1, bval1, cval1
2, aval2, bval2, cval2

table y (xid, key, otherval)
1, ABC, y1
1, DEF, y2
1, GHI, y3
2, ABC, y4
2, GHI, y5
```

what i want -

```
x.id, x.a, x.b, x.c, ABC, DEF, GHI
1, aval1, bval1, cval1, y1, y2, y3
2, aval2, bval2, cval2, y4, -, y5
```

what i dont want to do -

```
select
    x.id,
    a,
    b,
    c,
    ABC.otherval,
    DEF.otherval,
    GHI.otherval
from
    x,
    y ABC,
    y DEF,
    y GHI
where
    x.id = ABC.xid
    and x.id = DEF.xid
    and x.id = GHI.xid
    and ABC.key = 'ABC'
    and DEF.key = 'DEF'
    and GHI.key = 'GHI';
```

Is there another way ? I don't want to scan the same table 'y' thrice..

Comment: You are joining the same table on the same join condition three times. Why? Why not join once.

Comment: Do you know all possible `key` values at design time?

Comment: Yes, i know possible key values at design time. I may want only a subset of those keys. @usr, there was a typo earlier..

Comment: You're still joining the same thing three times which probably is just a typo. I'm unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, thanks, i had missed out those 3 filters !!

Comment: Whet version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition

Comment: Are subqueries acceptable?

Comment: Yeah, 'd like to learn all alternatives..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using 11g version of Oracle RDBMS, you can use `pivot` clause(if there are finite number of `key` values, because you'll have to manually specify them in the `IN` clause) to produce the desired result:

```
/* sample of data */
with  x (id1, a1, b, c1) as(
  select 1, 'aval1', 'bval1', 'cval1' from dual union all
  select 2, 'aval2', 'bval2', 'cval2' from dual
),
y (xid1, key1, otherval) as(
  select 1, 'ABC', 'y1' from dual union all
  select 1, 'DEF', 'y2' from dual union all
  select 1, 'GHI', 'y3' from dual union all
  select 2, 'ABC', 'y4' from dual union all
  select 2, 'GHI', 'y5' from dual
)
/* the query */
select  v1_id1      as x_id 
      , v1_xa       as x_a
      , v1_ab       as x_b
      , v1_ac       as x_c
      , v1_otherval as ABC  
      , v2_otherval as DEF
      , v3_otherval as GHI
  from ( select *
           from x
           join y
             on (x.id1 = y.xid1)
          pivot (
                  max(x.id1) as id1
                , max(x.a1)  as xa
                , max(x.b)   as ab
                , max(x.c1)  as ac
                , max(y.otherval) as otherval for key1 in ( 'ABC' as v1
                                                          , 'DEF' as v2
                                                          , 'GHI' as v3)
          )  
      )
```

Result:

```
      X_ID X_A   X_B   X_C   ABC DEF GHI
---------- ----- ----- ----- --- --- ---
         1 aval1 bval1 cval1 y1  y2  y3  
         2 aval2 bval2 cval2 y4      y5
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you ! I will try this on my original query!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select 
x.*,
(select y.otherval from y where x.id = y.xid and y.key = 'ABC') as ABC ,
(select y.otherval from y where x.id = y.xid and y.key = 'DEF') as DEF ,
(select y.otherval from y where x.id = y.xid and y.key = 'GHI') as GHI 
from x;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but wont this scan table y three times ?